# Get Chosen App from Intent.createChooser

Tags: java, android, android-intent, selection, getselection

I am trying to capture the result of `Intent.createChooser` to know which app a user selected for sharing.

I know there have been a lot of posts related to this:

- [How to know which application the user chose when using an intent chooser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613953/how-to-know-which-application-the-user-chose-when-using-an-intent-chooser?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137592/how-to-know-the-action-choosed-in-a-intent-createchooser?rq=1
- [How to get the user selection from startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Open file using..."), APP_PICKED);?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417019/how-to-get-the-user-selection-from-startactivityforresultintent-createchooserf)
- [Capturing and intercepting ACTION_SEND intents on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350531/capturing-and-intercepting-action-send-intents-on-android)

but these posts are somewhat old, and I am hoping that there might be some new developments.

I am trying to implement a [share action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) without having it be present in the menu. The closest solution to what I want is provided by [ClickClickClack](http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/) who suggest implementing a custom app chooser, but that seems heavy handed. Plus, it seems like there might be some Android hooks to get the chosen app, like the [ActivityChooserModel.OnChooseActivityListener](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b9f286e1a31bfc13e9c0e9635294742d558014c6/core/java/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.java).

I have the following code in my MainActivity, but the `onShareTargetSelected` method is never getting called.

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage());
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_prompt));

    ShareActionProvider sap = new ShareActionProvider(this);
    sap.setShareIntent(sendIntent);
    sap.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("Success!!");
            return false;
        }
    });

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 14):

As of API level 22 it is now actually possible. In Android 5.1 a method ([`createChooser (Intent target, CharSequence title, IntentSender sender)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender%29)) was added that allows for receiving the results of the user's choice. When you provide an `IntentSender` to `createChooser`, the sender will be notified by the chooser dialog with the `ComponentName` chosen by the user. It will be supplied in the extra named [`EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT) int the `IntentSender` that is [notified](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER).

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to capture the result of Intent.createChooser to know which app a user selected for sharing.

That is not possible.

Other "choosing" solutions, like `ShareActionProvider`, may offer more. I have not examined the `Intent` handed to [`onShareTargetSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html#onShareTargetSelected%28android.widget.ShareActionProvider,%20android.content.Intent%29) to see if it contains the `ComponentName` of the chosen target, though the docs suggest that it should.

And, if for some reason it does not, you are welcome to try to fork `ShareActionProvider` to add the hooks you want.

The reason why `createChooser()` cannot be handled this way is simply because the "choosing" is being done by a separate process from yours.

> I have the following code in my MainActivity, but the onShareTargetSelected method is never getting called.

`ShareActionProvider` goes in the action bar. You cannot just create an instance, call a couple of setters, and expect something to happen.

Comment: Alright. That's disappointing to hear, and is not that clear from the docs in the ShareActionProvider.

Comment: I ended up just going with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18980872/244526